# Dynamically render multiple JSON objects with Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

Given an app which searches songs from a rest api, the user is able to select a song from the resulting search, and append it to a playlist which is multiple `ul` lists. Each newly added result should be appended to a new object within the `songs` array in the JSON view below the playlist display. The JSON structure should look like this:

```
{
    title: 'Top 10 songs'
    songs: [
       {
           artist: 'artist name',
           album: 'name of album',
           note: 'note added from content editable line',
           imageurl: 'url to image'

       },
       {
           artist: 'artist name',
           album: 'name of album',
           note: 'note added from content editable line',
           imageurl: 'url to image'
       },
       {   
           artist: 'artist name',
           album: 'name of album',
           note: 'note added from content editable line',
           imageurl: 'url to image'
       },
       {...},
    ]
}
```

**This is my controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MusicController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
  fetch();
});

$scope.search = "";
$scope.listLimit = "10";
$scope.selectedSongs = [];
$scope.addItem = function(song){
    $scope.selectedSongs.push(song);
}
$scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedSongs.splice(index, 1);
};

function fetch() {
  $http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + $scope.search + "&type=track&limit=50")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.tracks.items);
      $scope.isTheDataLoaded = true;
      $scope.details = response.data.tracks.items;
    });
}

$scope.showJson = function() {
  $scope.jsonStringified = angular.toJson($scope.selectedSongs, true);
}
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="playlist">
    <h3 class="playlist-title" ng-model="playlistTitle">Top 10 Playlist</h3>
    <div class="songs" ng-repeat="song in selectedSongs track by $index | limitTo: listLimit">
      <div ng-repeat="artist in song.artists">
        <p ng-model="song.name">{{song.name}}</p>
        <p ng-model="artist.name">{{artist.name}}</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="song.note" placeholder="add note">
        <input type="text" ng-model="song.image" placeholder="add image url">
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</a>
        <pre class="result">
          [
          title: 'Top 10 Playlist'
          songs: [
            {
              album: '{{song.name}}',
              artist: '{{artist.name}}',
              note: '{{song.note}}',
              coverImage: '{{song.image}}'
            }
          ]
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Below is how the current result appears. It needs to only show the JSON one time, where each new song is added to the JSON as a new object, rather than its own JSON**:
[image: current]

**This is how it should appear, but there should be multiple objects within the JSON**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the ng-repeat up to the playlist div element

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="playlist">
      <h3 class="playlist-title" ng-model="playlistTitle">Top 10 Playlist</h3>

      <div class="songs" ng-repeat="song in selectedSongs track by $index | limitTo: listLimit">
        <p ng-model="song.name">{{song.name}}</p>

        <input type="text" ng-model="song.note" placeholder="add note">
        <input type="text" ng-model="song.image" placeholder="add image url">
        <a ng-click="remove(song)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></a>
      </div>
      <pre>
          [
          title: 'Top 10 Playlist'
          songs: [
        <div ng-repeat="song in selectedSongs">
        <div ng-repeat="artist in song.artists ">
          {
              album: '{{song.name}}',
              artist: '{{artist.name}}',
              note: '{{song.note}}',
              coverImage: '{{song.image}}'
            }
        </div>
      </div>
          ]
        }
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZGShtxSwo37gSWWDdTCE?p=preview)**

Comment: I previously tried that, but that's what gets you the JSON after every song. I need to have the JSON at the bottom of the list, and each song added should add a new object to the `songs:` array within the displayed JSON.

Comment: I think I need to add functionality to the `addItem` function in my controller to add the specific JSON fields to the JSON result, but not sure.

Comment: There is no add option. only remove is there.

Comment: Look at line 9 of the controller: `$scope.addItem = function(song){
    $scope.selectedSongs.push(song);
}`

Comment: can you create a plunker? use this https://plnkr.co/edit/ATn8mjbl0d86L4k8fQ2A?p=preview

Comment: Here's a plunker with the current state of the app: https://plnkr.co/edit/gQlbUDBrlQNntsPcG5P2?p=preview. Expand the view to see both columns.

Comment: nothing I can see. getting error. service call throws 400 bad request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144758/discussion-between-aravind-and-matt).